# Learning PostgreSQL after using MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, wiki, mediawiki

I'm looking for a simple resource for getting the hang of Postgres after using MySQL for years. So far I've figured out \l, \d, and \c, but I'm having trouble listing the tables in my MediaWiki installation.

The Postgres documentation is great, but I'm looking for something a bit more succinct. I've become accustomed to using show databases; use database; show tables, so it would be nice to have a quick reference page on the syntax differences between the two.

I haven't found anything yet, any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you reread the [Postgres documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/) which as a [list of SQL commands](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-commands.html). I'm not sure why you don't want to read it. It is an entirely different DBMS than MySQL, so knowing MySQL doesn't mean that you should skip the standard, up-to-date, complete, and detailed documentation that Postgres makes available for free.

Comment: +1 - Read The Manual! The Postgres team has written excellent documentation, better in fact than many commercial systems.

Answer (score 0):

As MarkM already said, you need to [**Read (at least the relevant sections of) The Manual.**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/) End of story. Game over. Do not pass go, do not collect $200.

In addition to the manual, Google is your friend: A very quick search on "Postgres for MySQL users" came up with [this page](http://www.coderholic.com/postgresql-for-mysql-users/), and I'm sure there are hundreds more like it out there.